# Facebook chat - X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM authentication

Tags: android, facebook, xmpp

I want to build an XMPP client on android, I've got it running perfect with authentication using Digest-MD-5, however when I try to convert it to X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM it keeps failing.

Comment: Can you extract the relevant part of your download into text in your question, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically the X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM authentication uses only a part of a access token. That is called the session key.

The access token is seperated by "|" characters, so you split the access token and only take the characters that are in the center. Refer below.

*********|a681464febcefb8********-***|***************

```
long callId = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;

            String sig = "api_key=" + apiKey
                            + "call_id=" + callId
                            + "method=" + method
                            + "nonce=" + nonce
                            + "session_key=" + sessionKey
                            + "v=" + version
                            + appSecret;

            try {
                sig = MD5(sig);
            }
            catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }

            String composedResponse = "api_key=" + URLEncoder.encode(apiKey, "utf-8")
                                        + "&call_id=" + callId
                                        + "&method=" + URLEncoder.encode(method, "utf-8")
                                        + "&nonce=" + URLEncoder.encode(nonce, "utf-8")
                                        + "&session_key=" + URLEncoder.encode(sessionKey, "utf-8")
                                        + "&v=" + URLEncoder.encode(version, "utf-8")
                                        + "&sig=" + URLEncoder.encode(sig, "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

I never got FB chat to work with my appSecret but used sessionSecret instead. You can get it using oldish REST API.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/auth.promoteSession/

This way you can keep your appSecret as a secret. Also it's worth noticing X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM authentication rarely succeeds on first try but requires 3-6 retries usually. Beats me why though as I'm using same session key and secret..