# C# XMPP X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM SASL implementation

Tags: c#, facebook, xmpp

I'm trying to integrate an application with [Facebook Chat](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/#platauth) in C#.  Facebook recommends the use of the X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM SASL mechanism.  The documentation describes X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM requiring the following parameters:

```
string method // Should be the same as the method specified by the server.
string api_key // The application key associated with the calling application.
string session_key // The session key of the logged in user.
float call_id // The request's sequence number.
string sig // An MD5 hash of the current request and your secret key.
string v // This must be set to 1.0 to use this version of the API.
string format // Optional - Ignored.
string cnonce // Optional - Client-selected nonce. Ignored.
string nonce // Should be the same as the nonce specified by the server.
```

From [this other Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709505/facebook-chat-x-facebook-platform-authentication) I was able to understand where the value of the session_key and sig come from, but I am having a hard time finding where the value of call_id is defined.  Also in the above mentioned link, the answer has the `sig` value as being:

```
string sig = "api_key=" + apiKey
                        + "call_id=" + callId
                        + "method=" + method
                        + "nonce=" + nonce
                        + "session_key=" + sessionKey
                        + "v=" + version
                        + appSecret;
```

Is there suppose to be anything separating the version and the appSecret?  The Facebook documentation doesn't say anything about including the appSecret, is it necessary to add?

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the post you linked, there was a definition for callId (top line)  As for appSecret, try it with and without.  If both work, there is your answer!

Answer (score 1):

See [Facebook Chat in C#](http://www.ianquigley.com/A91_Facebook_Chat_Authentication_in_C.html)