# how to sign in to facebook chat with gloox

Tags: facebook, chat, oauth-2.0, gloox

I used gloox to chat with my facebook buddy, and the authentication mechanisms is **X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM**.
Now I use **OAuth1.0 facebook sdk**, but facebook will change the sdk to **OAuth2.0**. and I do not know how to sign in to facebook chat with the access token.

now my Facebook Chat Authentication code before connection as follows:

```
client_.setSASLMechanisms( SaslMechFacebook );

 string key(ini.api_key);

  key += "|" + string(password) + "|" + string(ini.secret_key); 
//password is the session key  facebook returned

client_.setAuthcid( key );
```

How to change this code to adapt to the OAuth2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Before Oct 1st access_token had pipes in it, and now it's encrypted without the pipe symbols.  You can examples in [Facebook-chat-with-OAuth-2.0-example](https://github.com/jloomis/Facebook-chat-with-OAuth-2.0-example). Or check [sample example code here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/).

Also check accepted solution in question [Integrating Facebook chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221622/integrating-facebook-chat).